# Convert JSON DateTime to DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM am pm format

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datetime

I want to convert datetime format from `2015-03-17T06:14:49.2295964Z` to 
`17/03/2015 06:15 AM` via jquery or JavaScript.

Can you please help me understand this first format?

I have a controller method which returns datetime to ajax call i want to display this in `17/03/2015 06:15 AM` format but it is in `2015-03-17T06:14:49.2295964Z` format.

How can i convert it?
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: if possible, look at moment.js. full set of function to play with date time in javascript.

Comment: No i am using simple JavaScript to display dateTime retunred by controller.

Comment: I doubt, if native JavaScript has any set of function to do that for you. There might be some addition done in ECMA-6 but not sure. as of now I could suggest to write your own function to format it, its easy though. have a look on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.  This is a jQuery code. See https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

```
$.format.date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546", "Test: dd/MM/yyyy");
```